# Parbox for longtext

Tags: parbox

I'm looking for basic way of placing long text into parbox or some other box which will break the page if needed.

Please take a look at my code. What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\parbox[t]{0.15\textwidth}{\textbf{Intro}}
\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{\lipsum}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add some clarifications. Will your document contain more of these pairs of a short word and a long text? Probably something like a customized description environment could be useful instead of the parboxes.

Comment: do not use a box, they are not breakable, this should be set as a description list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxes are unbreakable, you want a list here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=70pt,labelwidth=60pt,labelsep=10pt]
\item[Intro]
\lipsum 
\end{description}

\end{document}
```